# Java: While Loop for entering username and password 3 times - Issue with break statement?

Tags: while-loop, break

I'm doing an assignment for class and want to create a loop that gives a user 3 opportunities to log in, entering the right username and password.

- When successful, giving the message "You are now logged in"
- When entered wrong 1-2 times, giving the message "wrong entry, try again (...)", then prompting to enter username and password again
- When entered wrong 3 times, giving the message "You have entered wrong three times (...)", then exit the system

Here is the part of my code:

```
System.out.println("Enter password");
String inputPassword = input.next();

int count = 0;

//create while loop, set loop continuation condition to count < 3
while (count <= 2) {            

    if ((!inputUsername.equals(userName)) || (!inputPassword.equals(password))) {       
        System.out.println("Wrong entry. try again: Enter username");
        inputUsername = input.next();

        System.out.println("Enter password");
        inputPassword = input.next();
    }   
    else
        System.out.println("You are now logged in");    

    count++;

    break;  
}

if (count > 2)
 System.out.println("You have enterede wrong three times. Please try again in a few hours");
 System.exit(0);
```

Any idea why the system exits after 2 failed attempts without giving me the error message "You have entered wrong three times (...)"?

I believe the problem lies in the "break" after incrementing the count, but not sure.

Without this break, in case of successful entry, the console displays "you are now logged in" 3 times followed by the error message "You have entered wrong three times (...)" - which is why I put it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `break` is unconditional. It will always run, meaning your loop will always exit on the first iteration.

Both the first 2 failed attempts happen before and during the first iteration, then you hit the `break` and exit. Since you've never looped though, `count` has only been incremented once, right before breaking.

I believe you intended to use curly braces to group the `break` under the `else`. Right now, since you aren't using curly braces, only the `println` statement is part of the `else`. ***Never omit curly braces***.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Carcigenicate!

That makes sense!

I have meanwhile found a solution. I have changed the continuation condition and it works!

```
int count = 0;

//create while loop, set loop continuation condition to count <2
while (count < 2 && ((!inputUsername.equals(userName)) || (!inputPassword.equals(password)))) {
    System.out.println("Wrong entry. try again: Enter username");
    inputUsername = input.next();

    System.out.println("Enter password");
    inputPassword = input.next();
    count++;    
}   
if ((inputUsername.equals(userName)) && (inputPassword.equals(password)))
    System.out.println("You are now logged in");
else
    System.out.println("You have enterede wrong three times. Please try again in a few hours");

    System.exit(0);
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your 'break' needs to move.

```
System.out.println("Enter password");
String inputPassword = input.next();

int count = 0;

//create while loop, set loop continuation condition to count < 3
while (count <= 2) {            

    if ((!inputUsername.equals(userName)) || (!inputPassword.equals(password))) {       
        System.out.println("Wrong entry. try again: Enter username");
        inputUsername = input.next();

        System.out.println("Enter password");
        inputPassword = input.next();
    }   
    else {
        System.out.println("You are now logged in");
        break;
    }            

    count++;
}

if (count > 2)
    System.out.println("You have entered wrong three times. Please try again in a few hours");

System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
System.out.println("Ghiane027");
String inputPassword = input.next();

int count = 0;

//create while loop, set loop continuation condition to count < 3
while (count <= 2) {            

    if ((!inputUsername.equals(Liezel Saleng)) || (!inputPassword.equals(Ghiane027))) {       
        System.out.println("Wrong entry. try again: Enter username");
        inputUsername = input.next();

        System.out.println("Ghiane027");
        inputPassword = input.next();
    }   
    else {
        System.out.println("You are now logged in");
        break;
    }            

    count++;
}

if (count > 2)
    System.out.println("You have entered wrong three times. Please try again in a few hours");

System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```java
System.out.println("Enter password");
String inputPassword = input.next();

int count = 0;

//create while loop, set loop continuation condition to count < 3
while (count <= 2) {            

    if ((!inputUsername.equals(userName)) || (!inputPassword.equals(password))) {       
        System.out.println("Wrong entry. try again: Enter username");
        inputUsername = input.next();

        System.out.println("Enter password");
        inputPassword = input.next();
    }   
    else
        System.out.println("You are now logged in");    

    count++;

    break;  
}

if (count > 2)
 System.out.println("You have enterede wrong three times. Please try again in a few hours");
 System.exit(0);
```